# Finding theoretical Earth Science that's approachable to the general public

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE:** Decided the question was off-topic on all SE sites, and as a result, deleted it. Thanks for the feedback!

---

This is a placeholder question for comments related to if the question "[Finding theoretical Earth Science that's approachable to the general public](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/579/finding-theoretical-earth-science-thats-approachable-to-the-general-public)" is not a good fit for EarthScience.SE since a number of comments have asked if the question should be on meta instead.

**(To be clear, my position is that while it might be a fit for meta, that is not the intent of the question - and only posting this meta question since it appears some users don't understand how to use meta or comments.)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blunders, I think the question is applicable to **All Sciences**, or even any academic persuit. It might be better answered on Academia.SE, though I am not sure that it is off-topic here either. Its like the question is at the triple point of a phase diagram.

Comment: +1 Maybe Academia.SE would be a better fit, since the [answer I posted on Earth Science](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/581/284) to my own question in "theory" would work for any domain that has theoretical concepts.

Comment: Decided the question was off-topic on all SE sites, and as a result, deleted it. Thanks for the feedback!